# Using VLookup in a macro

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm new to VBA but I'm hooked!  I've created a workbook that tracks overtime in 2 week blocks with one 2-week block per worksheet.  The macro I'm trying to debug is designed to carry any changes made in a worksheet over to following worksheets.  The trick is that the data in one row may be in a different row in following worksheets so I trying to use VLookup in a macro to keep it accurate.

```
Sub CarryForward()
    Dim Answer As String
    Answer = MsgBox("This should only be used for a PERMANENT crew change." & vbNewLine & "If you are adding a new person to the list," & vbNewLine & "please use the Re-Sort function." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Caution!")
    If Answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ActiveWorksheet As String
    ActiveWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
        For i = (ActiveSheet.Index + 1) To Sheets("DATA").Index - 1
            For x = 5 To 25
                Dim a As String
                Dim b As String
                a = "B" & x
                b = "C" & x
                ActiveSheet.Range(b).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(a, Sheets(ActiveWorksheet).Range("B5:C25"), 2, False)
            Next x
            Range("A3").Select
        Next i
    Sheets(ActiveWorksheet).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure it's just a syntax error in the VLookup line of code.  A lot of the help posted comes close to what I'm looking for, it just doesn't get me over the finish line.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier if we saw your file guidelines as to what you wanted, or at least a screenshot.

Comment: +1 for the above comment and also I would like to add that VBA is great but overdoing it is bad. I'm not sure that you need VBA to keep track of overtime unless you have quite specific needs.

Comment: It's contractual.  An employee union is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do, but reading between the lines I think

- you want to lookup the value contained in cell named by `a`?
- and put the result on sheet index `i`?

Also, there is a lot of opportunity to improve your code: see imbedded comments below

```
Sub CarryForward()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult  ' <-- Correct Datatype
    Answer = MsgBox("This should only be used for a PERMANENT crew change." & vbNewLine & _
        "If you are adding a new person to the list," & vbNewLine & _
        "please use the Re-Sort function." & vbNewLine & _
        "Do you want to continue?", _
        vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Caution!")
    If Answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Dim ActiveWorksheet As String  <-- Don't need this
    'ActiveWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name <-- use object variables
    Dim wbActive As Workbook  ' <-- don't select, use variables for sheet objects
    Dim shActive As Worksheet
    Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shActive = ActiveSheet
    'Dim a As String ' <-- no point in putting these inside the loop in VBA.  And don't need these anyway
    'Dim b As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = shActive.Range("B5:C25") ' <-- Use variable to hold range
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, x As Long '<-- dim all your variables
    For i = (shActive.Index + 1) To wbActive.Worksheets("DATA").Index - 1 ' <-- qualify references
        Set shDest = wbActive.Sheets(i)
        For x = 5 To 25
            'a = "B" & x <-- no need to create cell names
            'b = "C" & x
            ' I think you want to lookup the value contained in cell named by a?
            ' and put the result on sheet index i?
            '  Note: if value is not found, this will return N/A.  Add an error handler
            wbActive.Sheets(i).Cells(x, 3).Value = Application.VLookup(shActive.Cells(x, 2).Value, SearchRange, 2, False)
        Next x
        'Range("A3").Select
    Next i
    'Sheets(ActiveWorksheet).Select ,-- don't need these
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Range("A3").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked like a charm! I especially appreciate the tips on cleaning up the code.  Learning how and when to use variables for objects and such is also going to help for future needs.

Comment: I have a follow up question:  What is the purpose of

Comment: Follow up question:  What is the purpose of the variable shDest?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would want to replace the vlookup statement to be something like

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveWorksheet.Range(a).value, ActiveWorksheet.Range("B5:C25"), 2, False)
```

at the moment it looks like you're just doing a vlookup against some strings B5, B6, B7 etc instead of values in those cells

Comment: Thank You!  It worked like a charm!  I especially appreciate the tips on cleaning up the code.